# siunitx rounding works only if centering

Tags: tables, siunitx

Using the siunitx package

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

Consider the following two tables:

1.

```
\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-number-alignment=center, table-figures-decimal=3, table-auto-round]
}
  3.23958398 \\
\end{tabular}

% => 3.234
```

2.

```
\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-figures-decimal=3, table-auto-round]
}
  3.23958398 \\
\end{tabular}

% => 3.23958398
```

In the former, the number gets rounded, but in the latter it does not. Ran under both `pdflatex` and `xelatex`. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the second case, you have not set the `table-number-alignment` key, which will therefore take the default value `center-decimal-marker`. The later does *not* reserve space in the table for numbers of a particular size, and so `table-auto-round` does not apply.

The entire reason that `center-decimal-marker` is the default is precisely because it does not require any information about the size of the number in order to carry out alignment without any overfull boxes.